# Long Press Gesture in ArcGis Map in IOS

Tags: ios, arcgis

I'm working with ArcGis Map in my ios app. I'm trying to apply a long press gesture on it. But i'm getting an error `Value of type 'BCBaseMapView?' has no member 'addGestureRecognizer'` . How i can add long gesture on it. This is what i coded in it.

```
let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress))
    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    lpgr.delaysTouchesBegan = true
   // lpgr.delegate = self
    self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
@objc func handleLongPress(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer)
{
    print("longpressed")
    self.addWaypointOnMap()
}
```

This is my code i'm getting error on this line.

```
self.mapView.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
```

This is my mapView

```
var mapView: BCBaseMapView?
```

Comment: add code for, BCBaseMapView to get more information about it.

Comment: i have added check it. @BhavinKansagara

Comment: add code for class declaration for the BCBaseMapView, what is baseClass of it

Comment: It is a class of ARGIS map, i have imported ARCGIS in my class. I have check its definition it is showing AnyObject. @BhavinKansagara

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the superview of **BCBaseMapView** is **MKMapView** then try to add it on super view using:

```
self.mapView.super.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
```

OR

```
self.mapView.superview.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)
```

Comment: It is still showing this error : Value of type 'BCBaseMapView?' has no member 'superview' . @Satish Mavani

Comment: can you check that what is superclass of BCBaseMapView?

Comment: It is a class of ARGIS map, i have imported ARCGIS in my class. I have check its definition it is showing AnyObject. @Satish Mavani

Comment: i got it myself resolved  but ur answer helped me bit.